# RGraph (javascript) tooltips not working on bar chart

Tags: javascript, tooltip, rgraph

I have created this function that is passing in an array of numbers for the frequencies and an array of the alphabet as alphabet.

```
function buildGraph(frequencies, alphabet) {
    RGraph.Reset(document.getElementById('myCanvas'))
    //Bar Graph Creation
    var data = frequencies;
    tips = [];

    data.forEach(makeString);

    var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
        id: 'myCanvas',
        data: data,
        options: {
            backgroundGridAutofitNumvlines: 0,
            textAccessible: true,
            strokestyle: 'black',
            linewidth: 1,
            shadow: false,
            hmargin: 0,
            colors: ['Gradient(#aaf:blue)'],
            labels: alphabet,
            clearto: 'white',
            gutterBottom: 90,
            noaxes: false,
            crosshairs: true,
            tooltips: tips,
            tooltipsEvent: onmousemove,
        }
    }).wave({frames: 60}); 
};
```

and this function to make the data array into a string

```
function makeString(item) {
    tips.push(item.toString());
//    console.log(tips.toString());
};
```

But when these functions are implemented into my code with the tooltips, the tooltips do not display on the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have crosshairs and tooltips enabled at the same time. With crosshairs redrawing the canvas is necessary every time that you move the mouse - and redrawing hides tooltips.